# What is the best way to access context path in service layer for Spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, service, properties

What is the best way to access context path and other default properties in service layer for Spring boot project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get access to any properties is through `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` object.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;
```

Using this environment object you can get hold of any property set using external files or application.properties file or properties set using `@PropertySource`