# how to access values from application.properties file i dont ant to use @value and @configurationpropertiesin spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have tried this @Value("${userBucket.path}")

```
private String userBucketPath;
```

@ConfigurationProperties( prefix ="response")

but i don't want to use  @Value("${userBucket.path}")

```
private String userBucketPath;
```

@ConfigurationProperties( prefix ="response")

Because if any new property will come then every time i have to do @value or in @configurtion property i have to create or add new object i want that just i use last part of object name  and then i can access whole object for example response.app.abc.aa = aaa
response.app.abc.ab = abb in that i want to use just aa so it should show me aaa or if i used ab it should display abb only one place i need to write i.e. in application.properties and i can get that value but i don't want to use @value and @configurationproperties

Comment: why don't you want to use @Value and @ConfigurationProperties?
Show use your sample properties entries

Comment: You can use the `Environment` here.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281122/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-context-path-in-service-layer-for-spring-boot-pro/49281172#49281172

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't provided details about how your actually properties look like. Consider this code as an example. I am reading properties with a prefix and grouping them in a Hashmap.
Here is my typical properties file

```
spring.datasource.username: username
spring.datasource.password: password
```

here is my `@ConfigurationProperties`
The `ApppProperties` has a Map named as `datasource` and it wont change event if you add a new property like `spring.datasource.url`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring")       
public class ApppProperties {
    private Map<String, String> datasource = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getDataource() {
        return datasource;
    }
    public void setDatasource(Map<String, String> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }
}
```